# Homebrew install R without Xquartz on OS X

Tags: r, macos, homebrew, xquartz

Installing R with the pkg installer doesn't require XQuartz. However, install R with Homebrew requires to install XQuartz first.

Can anybody explain why please?

Is there a way to install R without Xquartz with Homebrew?

I need to decide whether to use Homebrew, or install R, Python etc with their pkg installers before applying to multiple computers (running OS X 10.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [**commit**](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/2434) on GitHub, it has been fixed.

> r: fix build with Quartz-only cairo #2434

Now, XQuartz is not required anymore, tested and it works:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [recipe](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/r.rb) you'll see you can pass `--without-x11` as a parameter (which should remove the need to have XQuartz installed. There is a cask for `xquartz`, btw. There is a recipe for [R GUI](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/r-gui.rb), as well.

Homebrew R has had some issues with RStudio in the past and is also not recommended by the R maintainers.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

I found that R works just fine without x.11 until I wanted to use the simple text editor. It complained about not having x.11, and wanted xquartz. I installed xquartz from home-brew and RStudio (and R) worked just fine. Hope that's useful.